# Intune ingest ADMX and enable client auto update for Zoom on Windows 10 Azure AD connected devices

Tags: azure, gpo, intune, zoom-sdk

I am trying to enforce Zoom auto update for Windows 10 laptops that are Azure connected. I have downloaded the Zoom ADMX file from here:  https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360039100051-Group-Policy-Options-for-the-Windows-Desktop-Client-and-Zoom-Rooms

I downloaded Windows Desktop Client Policies for version 4.6.0. I then ingest this into Intune as a custom profile with:
Name: Zoom
OMA-URI: ./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/ConfigOperations/ADMXInstall/Zoom/Policy/Zoom.
Data type: String
Value: Contents of Zoom_4.6.0.zip\Zoom_4.6.0\ZoomMeetings_HKLM.admx

Then I add another row with:

Name: Zoom - Auto-update
OMA-URI: ./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/ConfigOperations/ADMXInstall/Zoom/Policy/Zoom/EnableClientAutoUpdate_Policy.
Data type: String
Value:

When I try to save it I get:
Unable to save due to invalid data. Update your data then try again: The property 'isReadOnly' does not exist on type 'microsoft.management.services.api.omaSettingString'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

I am quite confused by this whole process to be honest as I am more familiar with setting GPO in Windows Server AD. My goal is to have zoom auto update for my users who are not domain joined but Azure AD joined. How can I achieve this? Appreciate any help. Once I have one working example I should be right.

Answer (score 2):

Since you loaded the ADMX with:

```
./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/ConfigOperations/ADMXInstall/Zoom/Policy/Zoom
```

You need to use the below to configure it:

```
./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Zoom~Policy~ZoomUsCommunication~zoomgeneral/EnableClientAutoUpdate_Policy
```

You can go to your registry and view:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\AdmxDefault\{GUID}
```

This will show you the custom ADMX loaded in step one and the values you need to use in step to. Remember to use the following to load the ADMX:

```
./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/ConfigOperations/ADMXInstall/ -
```

And the following to configure your options:

```
./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/
```

The string value should be:

```
<enabled/> <data id="EnableClientAutoUpdate_Policy" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For configuring as part of the app deployment, see [Zoom's support article](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362163-Mass-Installation-and-Configuration-for-Windows#h_1a305e31-454a-49e4-aab9-6bf24ca23119) and use `ZoomAutoUpdate="true"`.

For configuring on devices that already have Zoom installed - I'll research and update soon.